# Vertical controlgroup within jquery mobile header

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I want two buttons in a vertical controlgroup at the right end of a `jQuery` mobile header. Whatever I tried they were displayed horizontally, not vertically, until I accidentally added a duplicate `div` while editing. The `div`'s had a class of `ui-btn-right`. 
If I remove one of the `div`'s then it then fails - if I replace one `div` with a different `div`, it fails.

I made a `jsfiddle` to show what I mean... the home and back buttons are correct - but only because of the two duplicate divs near the top.

http://jsfiddle.net/Upland/szkk1jd8/

```
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="head">
    <img alt="Logo" src="https://cottonbureau.com/img/products/3899_wlCS_80.jpg" class="HEADLOGO">
    <div class="ui-btn-right" >  
    <div class="ui-btn-right" >  
      <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" class="headBut" data-icon="home">Home</a> 
        <a href="#" data-role="button" class="headBut" data-icon="back">Back</a> 
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
      <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Option One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option Two</a></li>
      </ul>  
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: So, what you mean is you want those 2 buttons stays vertically in middle of the ui-header?

Comment: Yes, as I said in the post, I want them exactly as they are now - see the jsfiddle.

Comment: Without your original codes, no way to give you a solution. Add your codes :)

Comment: What are my "codes"? There is a complete working demo in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am kind of confused on what you really trying to do. If you are trying to make the `buttons` stick to at `top-right` of the `header` after deleting the duplicate `div`, then here is the solution -

```css
.HEADLOGO { padding-top: 10px; }
.headBut   { width: 45px; height: 15px; display:block !important;}
.STATIC-FOOTER { text-align: center; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="page" id="ConsultantListing" data-title="Consultant Listing">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="head">
 <img alt="Logo" src="https://cottonbureau.com/img/products/3899_wlCS_80.jpg" class="HEADLOGO">
 <div class="ui-btn-right" >  
   <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">
     <a href="#" data-role="button" class="headBut" data-icon="home">Home</a> 
     <a href="#" data-role="button" class="headBut" data-icon="back">Back</a> 
   </div>
 </div>
      <div data-role="navbar">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Option One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option Two</a></li>
     </ul>  
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div data-role="content">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In vitae libero in augue lobortis aliquet vel eu diam. Sed nisl diam, eleifend fringilla quam et, interdum efficitur purus.</p>
  </div><!-- Content --> 
  <div data-role="footer" class="STATIC-FOOTER" data-position="fixed">
    Footer Text
  </div> 
</div>
```

Changes are -
1. Removed the duplicate div, and
2. Added `display:block !important;` on `.headBut` element

Comment: I am not sure what was confusing you - I was trying to remove the redundant <div> .... which you have solved for me now. Thank you